# I broke my openbox menu.xml by mistake

Tags: debian, openbox, crunchbang, nomodeset

I'm  on a Debian distro, it's been a long time that I edited Openbox menu.xml, so I forgotten that I had to use `obmenu` or whatever, I opened it in a normal text editor, edited something in the right-click menu. Then saved then restarted Openbox without reconfiguring it.

And now I can still login, after that all I see is a black screen with the mouse cursor. I tried opening the terminal using the Super key + T keyboard combination, but I can't see anything at all, no terminal, no web browser, just a cursor and a black screen.

Note, I can't boot to a live CD, due to a `nomodeset` issue. If `nomodeset` is on, my PC won't boot correctly, so I always set it to off, but when booting from a live CD, you can't set it to off.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-F2 to get into a tty. Login. Use `nano` or your preferred console text editor to fix your configuration.

Comment: @strugee just tried that, well i go to a black window and all i see is a white `-` sign, i typed nothing happens, i don't see text on the screen, just `-`, that's all i see

Comment: I would try Ctrl-Alt-F3 then. if not, reboot your computer. if you still can't get it to work, and don't have another desktop environment installed, you're just about screwed without a live cd.

Comment: i tried everything from f1 to f11, f7 doesn't enter tty, it exits them on my pc, other keystrokes gave me a black screen and i rebooted many times.... i have windows 7 installed and could do a third linux partition, fix  it from there and then delete it, if that an option

Comment: you're screwed without a Live CD. and there's no possible way that you can't set kernel parameters when you boot a Live CD. I suspect you just haven't poked around enough. anyway, your symptoms are much more serious than a mere Openbox issue. I don't know enough to help you fix it, but for when you Google for your problem, your symptom is that `getty` isn't run on any of your consoles on Debian. good luck.

Comment: although I guess if you really can't use a Live CD (and I'm convinced that you actually can), you could pass "init=/bin/sh" or "single" to the kernel when booting.

Comment: Some live let you set advanced options for the kernel command line, some Ubuntu let you just select nomodeset from a [popup](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Ctrl-Alt-F2 - F5 to bring up a tty login. After logging in you can open you menu.xml file with a text editor and fix the problem. Once finished run the `update-menus` command and then reboot the computer or kill the Openbox session.

Instead of restarting or killing the session, you might get lucky with the `openbox --reconfigure` command. Then just Ctrl-Alt-F7 (or whatever tty your GUI is on).

Comment: please read my comment above sir

Comment: I did, but I don't see anywhere there that you've tried `update-menus` or `openbox --reconfigure`.

Comment: that's because i don't see anything, the letters i type aren't showing on the screen so i can't edit the file

Comment: And Ctrl-Alt-F3, Ctrl-Alt-F4,Ctrl-Alt-F5 do the same thing? Openbox's menu.xml or X-Display shouldn't have any effect on other ttys.

Comment: please read my comment above, i tried everything

Comment: At the risk of getting a negative vote I'm going to sound like a jerk, but bare with me I'm trying to help you. Changing the menu.xml should absolutely have NO baring on other ttys unless something else happened as well. Hold down the ctrl button, the Alt button, and the F3 (or F2,F4, or F5) at the same time. It should take you to a completely seperate tty that has no connection to you GUI. IF it still doesn't take you to a shell login and a reboot still doesn't change the results, then you have no other option than to use a live CD to fix whatever is wrong which at that point isn't menu.xml.